# Highcharts: Best way to show related events to data

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, user-experience

I work with a lot of time series data that comes from various devices. In this post, I will just use an example of battery data because it's nice and simple. I can easily take the battery data and chart it over time in highcharts using the DateTime axis. I always have other event data that is important to know about because it gives you context to what you are looking at but doesn't need to be charted. As an example, Someone turned on or off a light. Knowing that gives you context why the battery usage has changed.  Today I put those in as a plotline. The problem with a plot like is that you are very limited on interacting with it. You can have a label but when you have a lot of plot lines close together the labels are a complete mess. I also can't really do a nice tool tip that would give the user more information about what they need to know. An example is they see the plot band and they see it was a "light turned on" event and they do something and they can see that a light with x watts turned on pulling Y amount from that battery. What works well for a plot band is that when I zoom in they are respond to the change.

I am looking for a solution, a pattern, an approach to allowing the user to display their time series based data with some related events that are overlayed over it. This approach would allow the user to dig into it a little bit to get context and a better understanding of their time series data

I don't know if this is something that is solved with Highcharts or if it's just a general UX problem. I am definitely looking for some help. Hightcharts is here to stay in this project but I can't seem to solve this problem

[image]

This is a sample battery chart that I made for this post. these are grey plot lines for events that are happening a lot and are really close together. As you can see the user has no context oh what they mean. They do know something has happened and can go crawl the data to see what those plots might be. In the real world, they know that grey is a debug event and they can dig into it from there but this really isn't a solving the problem

Answer (score 1):

You could:

**1**. use a separate `scatter` series to mark events with a specific point marker, which allows you to leverage the legend, data label, and
    tooltip functionality automatically

**2**. use the `plotLines` / `plotBands`, and create custom mousein/out events to
    mimic a tooltip

**3**. use the `flags` series type from Highstock

- http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-general

**4**. Use the *Annotate* plugin found in the Highcharts plugin repository

- http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry

Comment: Oh i had not stumbled upon the annotate plugin, i will go take a look at that to see if it is viable solution.